# How best to redirect all duplicates of "Why doesn't <Python string method> do anything unless you assign its result"?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

What's the best way to create and *name* a primary source question to redirect the high volume of Python questions asking why calling a string operation doesn't change the string.

**Naming this something friendly to new users and new-user searches will be crucial, because a person searching for "String method XYZ doesn't work" will never find "Why are Python strings immutable?"** (and even if they somehow could, its title and language won't seem related to answering their issue).

Every day now we're getting new ones, all these duplicates are just clogging the site, in many cases these could be closed-as-duplicate immediately:

- [*python string replace*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/python-string-replace)
- [*string.replace() doesnt seem to work*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781774/string-replace-doesnt-seem-to-work)
- [*python .lower() is not working*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28764550/python-lower-is-not-working/)
- [*This code snippet is not working for both upper case and lower case letters*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261180/this-code-snippet-is-not-working-for-both-upper-case-and-lower-case-letters/17261197#17261197)
- [*issue about replace() function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26009950/issue-about-replace-function/)
- [*'Replace' string function not working in Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121581/replace-string-function-not-working-in-python/)
- [*How to modify the content of a string using Regular Expression (Just like String.Replace)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194289/how-to-modify-the-content-of-a-string-using-regular-expression-just-like-string)
- [*Convert list to lower-case*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329113/convert-list-to-lower-case)
- [*string.upper() and .upper() won't execute*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461071/string-upperstr-and-str-upper-wont-execute)

The reference question sometimes used e.g. [Why are Python string immutable? Best practices of using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680080/why-are-python-string-immutable-best-practices-of-using-them) is **not** suitable for this purpose because the name is not intuitive, and it has way too much information for just this specific common issue. New users don't need a bloody essay on immutability and language design philosophies; they just need the one-liner "you need to actually assign the output of the string function/method call to something, it doesn't work just calling it in-place".

**UPDATE: Per my answer below, my suggestion is let's use [*Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)** ; I picked this and renamed it from "*python string replace*" since its answer is short and to-the-point, and it already has upvotes.

Comment: In theory, after some time all reasonable query terms will have been asked & marked as a duplicate of the reference question, and people searching for those terms end up at the reference question through the duplicates...

Comment: In JavaScript, the canonical duplicate is just called ["Replace method doesn't work"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1433212/1048572) though it could be "*Why doesn't the `replace` method change my string variable?*"

Comment: The reference question doesn't mention any of the built-in string methods like `replace`, `lower`, etc. It would probably be better if there was an answer added to it that better explained the issue with those, so it could actually be used as a duplicate target.

Comment: The [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) maintains a [list of canonical topics](http://sopython.com/canon/); we'd very much welcome discussion on the topic in that room.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that's nice, but never knew it existed till now! Why not integrate question suggestions automatically with *Close>Duplicate* functionality?

Comment: @smci: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I have asked for [search improvements when looking for duplicates]( [Boost duplicate post search results by incoming link count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232131)) where often-linked duplicates get a boost in the search results but that hasn't yet come to anything.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: ok well I just managed to boost the ranking of that question in the duplicates list from #7 to #3 just by using it 5 times in votes-to-close. So I think that's our solution.

Comment: It's not just Python, Java has the same problem.

Comment: @immibis: sure, but please keep the Java canonical duplicates separate.

Comment: Not a python person - is `X = sometext` valid or does it have to be `X = "sometext"`? If the latter then the posted question should be updated.

Comment: @dav_i We're in the process of fixing the issues in the question (look at the comments on the answer below).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's use [*Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

(I picked this and renamed it from "*python string replace*" since its answer is short and to-the-point, and it already has many upvotes)

Comment: If this question is chosen as the canonical it's contents must be gutted and replaced with a less careless asked question.

Comment: @usr: well tell us what solution you propose? Want to pick a different question? Rewrite that question? Wait for yet another question?

Comment: I edited the question and the answer to fit better. I'm not sure if you can do two edits together like that, so it may not pass. Pretty radical edits too. Worth a shot.

Comment: @CarlSmith: ok but your edit reads more like an answer, not a question... gotta make it feel like a question (maybe simply "What am I doing wrong?" rather than "Why do I need to assign the output?")

Comment: Changed it to *What am I missing here?*.

Comment: Well, I would at least remove all those paths and leave only a simple two-line code snippet. This question is not being used anymore by its author. It is to be repurposed.

Comment: Go ahead and change as you see fit, guys.

Comment: I don't know Python but I know the gutting procedure. Or should I say surgery? Crap-ectomy.

Comment: At this point I think the question has been rewritten enough to be a good, generic duplicate target.

Comment: The title you've changed it to doesn't reflect the actual question (i.e. the title includes the answer, whereas the question does not). Might I suggest doing `title = title.replace(" unless you assign its output", "")`?

Comment: @dav_i: I don't know, that's up for debate here, I asked how the canonical source should be named...?

Comment: Tadeck's answer in that question is not broad enough - need to make it clear this is nothing specific to `.replace()`, it's true for any of the ~20 Python string methods. So, I still can't accept this answer.

Comment: Three years later: I accepted my own answer, and rewrote [*Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out) for clarity and brevity.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with the same answer many times for many different questions. I do, however, have a problem with the same question many times. Thankfully they do have the "duplicate question" marker. The best way to handle many of the same question is to just start marking them as such.

To address what you've said above in a direct manner; a custom tailored answer to why "lower" does one thing and "replace" does another, even if they're the same sort of answer or the same answer phrased in different ways should be ok. They really are different questions even if the mechanics behind them are the same.

Comment: "They really are different questions even if the mechanics behind them are the same." No, they really are the same question; people expecting the method to change the object instead of returning a mutated value. They could trivially solve the question themselves (or at least arrive at a better question) by either reading the docs or spending 2 minutes in the repl. Also, if a user fails to understand how or why their question is a dupe that doesn't mean it's not a dupe. And if custom tailored answers to all special snowflake cases are ok that just means you could do away with dupes completely.

Comment: @l4mpi: we were all new users once, and many issues each of us encountered we were not able to trivially solve by reading the docs or spending 2 minutes in the repl

Comment: @smci speak for yourself - when I started with python, I was able to solve such issues by myself through experimentation. Furthermore, _SO is for professional and enthusiast programmers_ whom I would expect to experiment or at least read the documentation; especially in the case of python where it's extremely accessible (`pydoc str.replace` -> there's your answer). I can't stand the mentality of "just answer if the question is about strip instead of replace, the user can't be expected to make the mental leap to find out it's the same issue" which is expressed in this post.

Comment: @l4mpi: (I did solve many issues by myself, and I read the doc). I agree with you in objecting to wheaties suggestion here, but because it pollutes and diminishes the whole duplicate/redirect thing, which I think should be our primary motivation, not punishing perceived laziness.

Comment: @smci why not both? Answering every crap question instead of closing them (as duplicates, or as something else that gets deleted) pollutes and diminishes SO as a whole. But this is a by far broader discussion than the problem at hand here...

Comment: @l4mpi ok well my tl;dr is ***If you see a bunch of duplicate questions in burning need of a primary source, then create one by picking the best one you can find and suitably retitling as necessary, to be more general.*** (or, fail that, write the answer yourself)

Comment: @l4mpi I disagree strongly with the "not same question." If that were the case then almost half of dba.stackexchage would be reduced to a single question.

Comment: @wheaties I've only been to dba.SE a handful of times so I can't comment on that, but note that different communities can have different standards for duplicates, just as there are different standards for other types of closure. Doesn't change the fact that these questions are useless - while I can agree it makes sense to keep some of them around as signposts, I don't see any convinving argument for _answering_ all of them; they should IMO be closed with extreme prejudice. Otherwise, I could ask a question about `replace` and after you answer it ask the exact same question about `translate`...

Comment: @wheaties there seems to be sufficient disagreement and subjectivity that we have a basis for an even more basic MSO question ***'What are some objective standards for classifying "same question/not same question?"'*** (I searched MSO and don't find any suitable reference for that.)

Comment: @smci an excellent point. I think that is the largest stumbling block on this debate, though I admit from the voting it seems rather one sided and clear what the community thinks.

Comment: @wheaties: the community needs to actually **articulate** what those standards are, probably by means of example

Comment: It doesn't matter that an asker wouldn't have been able to find the master question; if they knew how to find the answer, they wouldn't have asked the question at all. There's no significant difference between "The answer is directly below your post" and "...is at the other end of this link on the same website". There are two goals: 1) get this person a solution to their problem 2) maintain a high-quality, easily-searchable archive of the solutions for future readers. Closing as duplicate _fulfills both those goals_; having answers spread across multiple questions hinders the second.