# Which of these four Java BufferedReader questions should I use as a duplicate target?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, canonical

Here are four essentially identical questions:

1. [Reset buffer with BufferedReader in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421653/reset-buffer-with-bufferedreader-in-java)
2. [How do I read a file again using buffered reader in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852276/how-do-i-read-a-file-again-using-buffered-reader-in-java)
3. [Java BufferedReader back to the top of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262618/java-bufferedreader-back-to-the-top-of-a-text-file/)
4. [How to return to the beginning of a Bufferedreader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28888835/how-to-return-to-the-beginning-of-a-bufferedreader)

I'd like to mark three of them as a duplicate of one but can't decide on the master question.

- 1:

  - Pro: Has the best *direct* answer to accomplish the specific goal in the question.
  - Con: Does not suggest alternative.
- 2:

  - Not up for consideration.
- 3:

  - Pro: The oldest.
  - Pro: Sage advice from Ryan P and Jon Skeet, presenting alternatives.
  - Con: Doesn't have a direct answer to the specific question (which could be seen as a good thing I suppose, unless somebody is actually trying to find out how to reset a `BufferedReader` for some good reason and is not interested in an alternative).
- 4:

  - Not up for consideration. I do like my answer ;) but really it contains no new information not scattered throughout the other three.

I think 1 and 3 are the top contenders. All of these are pretty specific to file-based sources, which is a general shortcoming, but not much can be done about that; I could add a new answer to whatever the master question ends up being along those lines, I suppose.

Another option, if a mod wants to spend some time on it, could be to merge 1 into 3 then mark 2 and 4 as a duplicate of 3. This would give the merged question a good selection of both direct answers and alternatives.

What do you guys think?

Comment: If you can't decide quickly, does it really matter?

Comment: @EJP Well, in real life, I have never been known as a person who can decide on *anything* quickly... my friends don't let me pick the restaurants any more. :(

Comment: Option 5: Create a new question that is designed to be a good duplicate target for these questions. Or just [hijack an existing one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287093/359284) and rewrite it so it does the same thing.

Comment: @KevinBrown: http://xkcd.com/927 Though if none of them is really good enough yet...

Comment: That's my point. If you can't decide anything at all, it's a bit pointless asking for advice on how to decide this specific matter. Concentrate on the restaurants, they're more important in the long run.

Comment: @EJP I usually just accept my poor decision making skills and leave the decision about where to eat up to my friends.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Moderators have a tool to deal with this type of sitation: [Merge](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/)

From [Handling Duplicate Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/handling-duplicate-questions/) (emphasis mine):

> These sometimes have multiple good answers attached to each question. **We will use our new moderator question merge function to merge them together without losing any answers or comments**.

Here is a screen shot of the moderator merge functionality (I'm a moderator on Webmasters and it came from there):

[image]

You could have a moderator merge the two questions that have good answers.    Then the other questions could me marked as duplicate of the merged one.

You could request the merge using a "needs moderator attention" flag and language such as:

> This question and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262618/ are duplicate, but there are good answers on each.  Can they be merged?

Comment: And maybe also put a link to this meta question in the flag reason.

Comment: This is what I went with; seems like the best option. Requested merge of 1 into 3, preserving 3. Then I'll mark the rest as duplicates of 3.